# How do I avoid walls of If statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I heard several times that coding like this is suboptimal:

```
if weapon == "sword":
 print("Knight") 
elif weapon == "katana":
 print("Samurai") 
elif weapon == "axe":
 print("Viking")
```

How do I write such code optimally?

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store these associations in a dictionary

```
weapons_roles = {
    "sword": "Knight",
    "katana": "Samurai",
    "axe": "Viking"
}
```

1. Print something, whenever the key is not in the dict

   ```
   print(weapons_roles.get(weapon, "No role"))
   ```
2. Print a role only if the weapon is known

   ```
   if weapon in weapons_roles:
       print(weapons_roles[weapon])
   ```

Comment: This is the best answer since it handles the cases where the weapon might not exist in the dict

Comment: Slight nit: this prints something whether there is a match or not, while the original code only printed something if there was a match (i.e., there was no `else` clause). That can be handled by using a `try` statement to catch (and ignore) a `KeyError` raised by `weapons_roles[weapon]`.

Comment: @chepner or just with an if

Comment: I might continue to use `get` with the `if` statement, to avoid repeating the lookup. `role = weapon_roles.get(weapon); if role is not None` or `if (role := weapon_roles.get(weapon)) is not None:`. This is even a slighter nit, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

```
def example_function(weapon):
    weapon_dict = {'sword': 'Knight', 'katana': 'Samurai', 'axe': 'Viking'}
    return weapon_dict[weapon]
```